# docker-compose run commands after up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  nd-db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: nd-data
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data
      - type: volume
        source: nd-sql
        target: /sql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER="admin"

  nd-app:
    image: node-docker
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: ndapp-src
        target: /src/app
      - type: volume
        source: ndapp-public
        target: /src/public
    links:
      - nd-db

volumes:
  nd-data:
  nd-sql:
  ndapp-src:
  ndapp-public:
```

nd-app contains a migrations.sql and seeds.sql file. I want to run them once the container is up.

If I ran the commands manually they would look like this

```
docker exec nd-db psql admin admin -f /sql/migrations.sql
docker exec nd-db psql admin admin -f /sql/seeds.sql
```

Answer (score 4):

When you run `up` with this docker-compose file, it will run the container entrypoint command for both the nd-db and nd-app containers as part of starting them up. In the case of nd-db, this does some prep work then starts the postgres database.

The entrypoint command is defined in the Dockerfile, and expects to combine configured bits of [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) and [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd). What you might do is override the ENTRYPOINT in a custom Dockerfile or [overriding](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#entrypoint) it in your docker-compose.yml.

Looking at the [postgres:9.6 Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/87b15b6c65ba985ac958e7b35ba787422113066e/9.6/Dockerfile), it has the following two lines:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["postgres"]
```

You could add the following to your nd-db configuration in docker-compose.yml to retain the existing entrypoint but also "daisy-chain" a custom `migration-script.sh` step.

```
entrypoint: ["docker-entrypoint.sh", "migration-script.sh"]
```

The custom script needs only one special behavior: it needs to do a passthru execution of any following arguments, so the container continues on to start postgres:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -exo pipefail
psql admin admin -f /sql/migrations.sql
psql admin admin -f /sql/seeds.sql
exec "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `docker-composer -f path/to/config.yml name_of_container nd-db psql admin admin -f /sql/migrations.sql` work?

I’ve found that you have to specify the config and container when running commands from the laptop.

Comment: I was hoping to find a way that I could run the commands within the docker-compose file. Just run docker-compose up and have the application build and the commands run automatically.